# Send and receive money using Paypal API in .Net MVC

Tags: .net, paypal, asp.net-mvc-5, payment

I am developing one .Net MVC application. Application has list of users and any user can send money to any registered user. It working using one third party payment gateway.

Now I want to rewrite this functionality using Paypal. I have installed Paypal Nuget package (version 1.9) but I don't know which method should I use.
Also, I have seen in Paypal mass payment documentation but I want to send money to one user at a time.
It would be great if I get some sample code.

Let me know which scenario is suitable in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your account will be sending the money, then you need to use Payouts (successor to Mass Payments). The first thing you need to do is have the business owner of the acount request access. [Here is how to request access](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts).

Comment: Hello @Preston. Thanks for the answer.
I implement Payout code. I can able to send money to another user. But I can not able to send from any other payer. Payout object doesn't have any payer property.
The application should be sending money from any user to any user

Comment: Using a regular PayPal Checkout (not Payouts), you can set up a checkout to a custom payee: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/

Comment: Is it possible to set Payer and Payee in Paypal object? because I need both of them.
Let's say I have created a Sandbox account and I can send money to B user. So it will send money from my Account to user B. Now If user B login into website and he wants to send money to user C at that time I can not able to set Payer object email.

Comment: No, anyone can use a button to checkout -- the button (with a payee set) should only display when a logged in user who should be paying is logged in.  If user B logs in, the button will render with payee:C.  If user C logs in, the button will render with whoever they should be paying. And so on.